# Is this enough work to show that $f$ is continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity

> Let $$ f(x) = \begin{cases} x^2 \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) & \text{if } x \neq 0 \\ 0 & \text{if } x=0\end{cases}$$ Is $f$ continuous? Is $f$ differentiable?

$\text{I know how to show that this function is differentiable}\\\text{ but is there a way to show that it is continuous? Should I use the three step continuity test?}$

$\\ \text{If x } \neq 0 \text{ then} \\ f'(x) = 2x\sin\frac{1}{x} + x^2 \cdot(\cos \frac{1}{x})\cdot\frac{1}{x^2} \\ = 2x\sin\frac{1}{x}-\cos\frac{1}{x}, x \neq 0 \\ f'(0) = ? \\ f'(0) = \lim \limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h }\\  \lim \limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f(h)}{h } = \lim \limits_{h \to 0} \frac{h^2\sin \frac{1}{h}}{h} = \lim \limits_{h \to 0} h \sin h \\ h\neq 0 \\ 0 \le |h\sin\frac{1}{h}| \le |h| \\ \lim \limits_{h \to 0} |h| =0 \\ \lim \limits_{h \to 0} 0 =0 \\ \lim \limits_{h \to 0} |h \sin \frac{1}{h}| =0 \text{ pinching theorem} \\  \lim \limits_{h \to 0} h\sin\frac{1}{h} =0 \\ \text{i.e.} f'(0) =0 \\ \text{f is differentiable on } \mathbb R. \\  f'(x) =
\begin{cases}
2x \sin \frac{1}{x} - \cos \frac{1}{x},  & x \neq 0 \\
0, & x=0
\end{cases} \\ \text{ Is this enough to show that f is continuous?} $

Comment: Unless you are looking for an independent proof for continuity, once you have established differentiability then continuity follows from it.

Comment: Should I start by showing continuity by using the three step continuity test for it? Can I just go straight to differentiability ?

Comment: since there are two questions and assuming you want to answer them in order. First we can show continuity, then differentiability. Of course here, the function is differentiable so you get continuity for free. For continuity: you need to establish $0=f(0)=\lim_{h \to 0}f(h)$ (since $x=0$ is the only point where things are changing).

Comment: If you just want continuity, you can get it in one line from the "pinching theorem".  You say "the three step continuity test" like you expect people to know what that is, but they probably don't (I certainly don't); this isn't a standard term and is probably something invented by your textbook / instructor.